# Placing a link on facebook wall counts as a like?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, sharing

Since a few days I have noticed that sharing a link also counts as a like in the external facebook widgets. As we have certain sites that count the number of likes for certain pages this doesn't seem to be accurate anymore. Anyone else who can confirm this "issue"?

Comment: Inaccurate "Like" count? Please double check the page URL is the same as the "like" URL of your Facebook widget.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I double checked the URL's they are exactly the same. The issue actually is when i share a link on my wall (or on anyone else's wall) that this counts as a like when the page itself is'nt liked at all.

Comment: have you "subtracted" the like counts of admins?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Don't think this is going to make a difference since i'm talking about a difference of a thousand likes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the Like plugin and not the Like count of a Facebook page, please see the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Specifically the piece labelled `What makes up the number shown on my Like button?`

The number on an off-Facebook like button is made up of several different types of interactions, not just Like edges

Comment: Thanks exactly the information i was looking for, the number of likes coming from the graph api is made up only from likes or is this a combination of likes, comments, shares and DM's aswell? Since we used one of these widgets on a contest site we are looking for a way to only get the number of likes. Thanks!